# How can these two people be proven innocent until proven guilty?

Tags: civil-procedure, theft, criminal-procedure

I lost some money and USB cable in my bag.
On this particular day I asked for a usb cable from a female workmate who was still on her assignment and I was as well on an asignment in a different location.
Around 2pm she sent me a text message saying I must leave the usb cable in the camp(where 9 of us as a team are based momentarily). I explained to her that I was far from the camp and will come to the camp at exactly 6pm. I arrived at the camp at 5:40pm but before I went to the camp I passed through my business place to collect £250 and with the initial £150, I had £400 cash which was safely put in my backpack. I then went to convert the two £50s into £100 note so I could have 4 of £100 notes and safely put them back in the backpack and on top of the money was placed a wet tshirt folded in a long sleeved shirt and on top of the shirt was powerbank connected to a tablet, charging and the backpack was zipped up. I then went to the camp at 5:40pm and placed the bag on my space known by all camp members and went to attend to my friend(not part of the camp) and after thirty minutes time I was again back to the camp. To my surprise I did not find my packed items in the backpack same as they were packed, the wet tshirt was on top of the tablet and the tablet was not connected to the powerbank and actually there was not a usb cable. When leaving the bag was my team member washing, who reminded me to leave the usb cable for owner while I was on my way to see a friend(not a camp member). I asked if the owner came for cable which he affirmed and proved that she came for it but entered inside the camp room while he was outside and did not see what she touched except his powerbank and his usb cable which according to him, she actually asked and she was granted permision by him to go and get it by herself in a shared room, which I and him do share. Now since she refused to have collected the usb cable and my money amounting to £400, and the police cannot make a judgement based on my statement. how would different laws interpret this case

Comment: Please, would you try to sort the post in a way that it is understandable? The order of things is all over the place and some things seem to miss. Also, we don't give legal advice here.

Answer (score 2):

From the police perspective, they only consider whether a crime was committed. They may conclude that there was a theft of money based on your statement, provided that they correctly comprehend the report of the events. However, nothing that you reported provides a high enough level of evidence to accuse a specific person of theft. In common law jurisdictions, there must be some level of evidence that a person committed a crime, to detain the person for a crime. If this took place in the US, the evidence is not specific enough to allow detention, but further investigation would be possible. On the assumption that they concluded that no more evidence will come forth, that is probably the end of the criminal path. In case this was in Zambia, the same “reasonable suspicion” [requirement for warrantless arrest](https://acjr.org.za/acjr-publications/fact-sheet-22-arrest-without-warrant-zambia.pdf) seems to hold there.

Another possibility is a civil action. But again, the problem is that without stronger evidence as to who took the money, the prospects for recovery are low. Unlike a criminal case, the plaintiff (you) only needs to make a showing that it is more likely than not that the defendant took the money. If the suspect denies having retrieved the cable but there is contrary testimony that she entered the room where the cable is, then this is a reasonable grounds for thinking that she is lying (but there could be a counter-story such as “I went to get the cable but received an emergency call before getting it”).

Basically, the law gets into interpreting fact only when the facts are established.